# permission denied and bad interpreter when attempting to run awscli in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have tried to use the code below to run awscli in a virtual environment. I can activate it and install awscli, but run into permissions issues after. The first shows me trying to set execute permissions on aws, but that leads to a 'bad interpreter error'. The second attempts to run awscli with no changes to permissions. It's just an install and run. Does anyone have a suggestion for a next step?

Thank you.

Example 1:

```
stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                scl enable rh-python36 -- python -m virtualenv testvenv
                . testvenv/bin/activate
                echo WORKSPACE:"${WORKSPACE}"
                python -m pip install awscli
                chmod +x "${WORKSPACE}"/testvenv/bin/aws
                aws ec2 describe-instances
            }
        }
}

bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

Example 2:

```
stages {
            stage('Build') {
                steps {

                    scl enable rh-python36 -- python -m virtualenv testvenv
                    . testvenv/bin/activate
                    python -m pip install awscli
                    aws ec2 describe-instances
                }
            }
    }

    WORKSPACE/awscli/bin/aws: Permission denied
```

Comment: You don't have any quotes around the commands anywhere? Or any steps declared in your `steps` block?